# What is it kind of data?

Tags: swift, websocket

[image]

I use Starscream pod. When I send "KID: NOOP - sendMessage: Test from kid" from client, server got data as at picture

Please help to understand how to read this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of data is just a string `"Test from kid"`, it is **not** JSON.

To get the string write

```
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

---

A hint:

When you print Swift 3 `Data` bridge cast the object to `NSData`

```
print(data as NSData)
```

to see the raw bytes. If most of the values are between 32 and 127 (hex `0x20` - `0x7F`) the data represents a readable string.